# $a-b = (e + (a<<s)-(b<<s))>>s$, why it does not work for some $e$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic, bit-strings

If I subtract 2 numbers shifted left to a number and shift right, I get the original number. Example:

$$30 - 1 = ((30<<7) - (1<<7)) >> 7 = 29$$

or in other words

$$a-b = ((a<<s)-(b<<s))>>s$$

The $s$ is chosen carefully so $a<<s$ and $b<<s$ are so big that a small number $e$ added to $(a<<s)-(b<<s)$ won't interfere with the result. In theory, this small number would get added to the lower bits, which would disappear when shifted right again:

$$a-b = (e + (a<<s)-(b<<s))>>s $$

However, in practice, this does not happen:

$$
((30<<7) - (1<<7)) >> 7 = 29\\
(-4 + (30<<7) - (1<<7)) >> 7 = 28
$$
why the results are different?

Comment: If $e$ is *positive* and small, then adding $e$ doesn't change the bits. However, subtracting $e$ (or adding a negative $e$) can change higher bits due to the carry that occurs in subtraction.

Answer (score 1):

Your assumption that *$e$ added to ... won't interfere"* does not hold for negative $e$ because a negative number has (formally) infintely many set high bits when written in 2's complement.  For example, take 8-bit numbers then

`-2 = 11111110`

in 2's complement.

---

What you are trying to do is to manually form a bit-field where the lower $k$ bits encode $e$ and the upper $n-k$ bits encode $a-b$.  **You can do that, but** you'll have to mask out the upper bits of $e$.  When you are decoding the packed value, **you'll have to restore the upper bits of $e$** again, i.e. you'll have to sign-extend the signed $k$-bit number $e$ to a signed $n$-bit number.

Here is an example output of a Python3 code.  C/C++ would be mostly the same$^1$.  $e$ is encoded in the lower 4 bits, and $ab$ is encoded in the upper 8 bits:

```
ab=+11=000000001011, e= +3=000000000011  =>  enc=000010110011  =>  ab=+11, e= +3
ab=-11=111111110101, e= +3=000000000011  =>  enc=111101010011  =>  ab=-11, e= +3
ab=+11=000000001011, e= -3=111111111101  =>  enc=000010111101  =>  ab=+11, e= -3
ab=-11=111111110101, e= -3=111111111101  =>  enc=111101011101  =>  ab=-11, e= -3
                   bit 3 is the sign-bit of encoded e ---^
```

Notice how the higher bits are all '1''s for negative values.

The respective Python3 follows. `encode` encodes `e` into the 4 LSBs and `ab` into the upper 8 bits.  As `e` will be encoded in signed 4-bit, it may range from $-8$ to $7$.  `decode` decodes the values and sign-extends `e` as needed.

---

$^1$In C/C++ you might raise Undefined Behaviour when you shift a signed value left and it overflows.  Hence, in C/C++ always operate on `unsigned` values internally to avoid UB.  But in C/C++ one would likely prefer bit-fields.

---

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

def encode (ab, e, bits_e):
    # Encode E in lower BITS_E bits and AB in upper bits.
    mask_e = (1 << bits_e) - 1
    e_max = mask_e >> 1
    # E is supposed to be signed
    assert e <= e_max and e >= -e_max-1
    return (ab << bits_e) | (e & mask_e)

def decode (val, bits_e):
    # Decode E from the lower BITS_E bits of VAL and AB from upper bits.
    mask_e = (1 << bits_e) - 1
    ab, e = val >> bits_e, val & mask_e
    if 1 & (e >> (bits_e - 1)):
        # if the sign-bit is set, then sign-extend E.
        e |= -1 << bits_e
    return ab, e

def bits (x):
    # 12-bit binary representation as string.
    return "{0:b}".format(x & 0xfff).zfill(12)

def show (ab, e, bits_e):
    enc = encode (ab, e, bits_e)
    dec_ab, dec_e = decode (enc, bits_e)

    print ("ab=%+3d=%s, e=%+3d=%s  =>  enc=%s  =>  ab=%+3d, e=%+3d"
           % (ab, bits(ab), e, bits(e), bits(enc), dec_ab, dec_e))

show (+11, 3, 4)
show (-11, 3, 4)
show (+11, -3, 4)
show (-11, -3, 4)
```

Note: Instead of sign-extending by means of `e |= -1 << bits_e` you can also do `e -= 1 << bits_e` if preferred.